# Android intent filter scheme doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I'm trying to build a simple Android app that sends a Youtube URL to a particular media server. On the Android side, it needs to be activated by the user pressing the share button on a video inside the Youtube app (or browser). However, I'm having extreme difficulty working out how intent filters work in this case.

The following code, for example, makes my app show up in the apps list when I share from youtube (or almost anything else for that matter).

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
    </activity>
```

However, when I replace the  element with anything containing a scheme, for example:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="https" />
```

The app no longer appears in the sharing list. I've tried every combination, and nothing seems to work. Any suggestions (general about intent filters, or more specific to Youtube)?

EDIT:
After investigation using Intent Interceptor, I've discovered that links (e.g. from Youtube or the browser) are sent with the DATA field sent to NULL. Other types of intent (for example, a file) appear to have this set to the URL of the file. Presuming that the filter scheme/host/path act on the DATA section of the intent, there is no data there to filter, so links can't be filtered in this regard. Can anyone confirm or clarify this?

Comment: please try this : <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />

Comment: @dex - doesn't work :(